# Can we delete single column data which is using ID of its row with the help of my procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have one special case in my sql server 2008. I want to delete single column data which is using ID of its row with the help of my procedure. How can i achive this can any one please help me?

Comment: Can you please describe your question in details ?

Comment: what do you mean 'delete data'? set field value to null?

Comment: Yes..I have a table with 10 columns.But i want to delete a single column data using my procedure.For Example if Id=1001  in this row i want to delete some specified column data.Can i do this?

Comment: If(Id=1001) delete Mycolumn from Mytable where Id=@Id;this is i want use from procedure

Answer (score 0):

You say that you want to do

```
If(Id=1001) 
delete Mycolumn 
from Mytable 
where Id=@Id;
```

You can't "delete" a column in a specific row as all rows must have exactly the same columns.

I assume you need something like this.

```
UPDATE Mytable 
SET Mycolumn = NULL
WHERE Id=@Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove column or set data to null ?

If you want to set data to null then try this :

```
UPDATE tablename
SET colname = NULL 
WHERE Id=@Id;
```

if you want to remove column then try ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN command